# JavaScript mocha/chai/sinon code coverage browser only no node

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I was wondering if there is a tool to do code coverage of JavaScript using only the browser.  Googled around a bit but didn't find any good answer. I need to try this without node (for whatever reason I don't want to mention).

Comment: What does "JavaScript using only the browser" mean?

Comment: well I am trying to be  helpful with the question.  Assume that means I only have html, css, js files.  No node or anything else.  Just trying to cover for those pedantic types...